# Incorporate a single login for a Drupal 8 intranet site using Active Directory logins

Tags: active-directory, ldap, single-sign-on, drupal-8

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I am building our company intranet using Drupal 8 and I want to incorporate usernames and passwords that are set up already in the IT dept with Active Directory. I am overwhelmed at this point. Does anyone know of a good tutorial or can you direct me to the correct modules?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: You need the ldap module : https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the Ldap module : https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap
Easy to configure and comes with multiple features like mixed authentication (ldap/drupal), automatic creation of Drupal accounts, and also can handle ldap authorizations mapping with drupal roles when combined with authorizations module.
Hope this will help you.